# Memory Game in JS: Difficulty levels are not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

SOF community!

My girlfriend is learning to code. She is doing a course which final assignment is a memory game using HTML5, CSS3, and Javascript.

She has achieved great progress, however, we haven't figured out how to make difficulty levels work, namely, easy, medium, and hard.

What has she accomplished so far?

- She created a modal (jQuery) with three buttons - easy, medium, and hard.
- She created a function that counts every time two cards have
  been flipped over.
- This counter function is **inside** the function `checkForMatch()` that verifies if two cards are a match or not.

The problem

She started by experimenting with an `easy()` function that displays an alert when the counter reaches 9 movements. This level function is inside `checkForMatch()` and *it works*.

**However**, when she adds the two levels left (medium and hard), **the game will only take the first level** (`easy()`) regardless if the player chooses medium or hard.

Level functions are coded this way:

```
function easy() {
  $.modal.close();
  main.style.display = 'block';
  if(contador_movimientos == 6) {
    alert('lose');
  }
}
```

It is important to highlight that the buttons are bound to the following events:

```
facil.addEventListener('click', easy);
intermedio.addEventListener('click', medium);
experto.addEventListener('click', hard);
```

Just in case, *facil* (easy), *intermedio* (medium) and *experto* (hard) are buttons in HTML.

We updated the `checkForMatch` function as follows:

```
function checkForMatch() {
let isMatch = firstCard.dataset.framework === secondCard.dataset.framework;
isMatch ? disableCards() : unflipCards();
easy();
contador();
}
```

I am not an expert, but I think the variables bound to the buttons aren't doing anything in particular, which explains why the level functions overlap (they are always active).

A given difficulty level should be only activated if its bound button is clicked.

Thank you so much so far for all the guidance!

Comment: `medium() && hard() == false;` is a really strange syntax, especially if medium() and al. really are functions, and with the double = (test, not assign) and the && on the left hand side...

Comment: `if (easy() == true) {` makes no sense, because the `easy()` function doesn't return true or false, instead it appears to actually cause the "easy" logic to run and check the user's score. That's just one example. the comment above also alerts you to some logic which doesn't make sense. It's hard to know what the code is trying to achieve. The logic seems to get confused between _setting_ the difficulty level, _checking_ the current difficulty level, and actually _playing the game at that difficulty_.

Comment: **Thank you so much for getting back to me so quickly!**. You are right, the Boolean logic doesn't make sense if the functions do not return a True/False statement. We will go back to work and see what else can we do. I think I will edit the whole post to add more clarity. Thanks again, guys/girls!